# Recommended way to approach rotations in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, quaternions

I'm currently writing my transformation implementation in my OpenGL program. I am at the point where I need to code in rotations. Here's the question:

I'm on board with quaternions, but the vertex shader is not (e.g. there is no quaternion "multiplication" in the GLSL language, as far as I'm aware). While I can appreciate the usefulness of quaternions, it seems that I have to use a matrix in the end anyway. What should I do? Do I go with quaternions and convert them to a transformation matrix, or is there something else I'm missing and should be doing (maybe hardcoding the quaternion multiplication in the vertex shader)?

Comment: well, you don't *create* quaternion's in GLSL, you convert your quaternion to a rotation matrix, and use it in the model matrix. Are you using GLM in your program?

Comment: I'm not using GLM since I'm coding my program in C, but I've got enough math background to handle all the math stuff. I was asking because I wanted to know the most efficient way to implement rotations.

Comment: the resource I linked in my answer goes in depth about the best way to implement rotations. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great resource to understand rotations in modern OpenGL is reading [Tutorial 17: rotations](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-17-quaternions/) from opengl-tutorial.org. I won't copy the page word for word, but in short,

You don't use quaternions inside GLSL. Convert your quaternion to a rotation matrix, and use it in the Model matrix. Your vertices will be rotated as usual with your Model - View - Projection Matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you can just compose all your transformations into single model-view-projection matrix and pass it into shader.

But in case you need to perform quaternion rotation in glsl (for example you can use quats to save memory) then you can use this code for rotating vector by normalized quaternion:

```
vec3 quat_transform( vec4 q, vec3 v )
{
    return v + 2.*cross( q.xyz, cross( q.xyz, v ) + q.w*v ); 
}
```